# Loading saved UIImage

Tags: xcode, uiimage

I am trying to save a screenshot of my device for later use in this way:

```
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)])
     UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
else
     UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
 UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
 UIGraphicsEndImageContext();                       

//NSString *tmpPngFile = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"background55667.png"];
  NSString  *pngPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/background55667.png";
 [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:pngPath atomically:YES];
```

...but I can't seem to be able to open it and display it in a UIImageView. something like this:

```
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory()  stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];

// Write out the contents of home directory to console
NSLog(@"Documents directory: %@", [fileMgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:&error]);

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:....];
backGroundPhoto.image = image;
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[UIImage imageNamed:]` is for loading images which have been included in the app bundle.

Assuming your path is correct you can load it by

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: pngPath];
```